# What is the default return value of a Dart function?

Tags: dart, return

The function below works even though I intentionally deleted 'return' command:

```dart
main() {
  add(i) => i + 2; //I intentionally deleted 'return'
  print(add(3)); //5
}
```

But, the function below doesn't work after I intentionally deleted the 'return' command.

```dart
main() {
makeAdder(num addBy) {
 return (num i) {
    addBy + i; //I intentionally deleted 'return'
  }; 
}

 var add2 = makeAdder(2); 
  print(add2(3) ); //expected 5, but null.
}
```

**Edited to clarify my question.**

The last sentence in the latter function above, add2(3) doesn't return a value(I expect 5) but just null returns.

My question is why 'addBy + i' of the latter function doesn't return contrary to the fact that 'add(i) => i + 2' of the first function returns 'i + 2'.

**Edited again**.
**The answer is in the fact of '=>' being {return }, not just {}.**

```dart
main() {
makeAdder(num addBy) => (num i) { return addBy + i; }; 


 var add2 = makeAdder(2); 
  print(add2(3) ); // 5
}
```

Even the code below works as '=>' has 'return' command in it.

```dart
main() {
makeAdder(num addBy) => (num i) => addBy + i; ; 


 var add2 = makeAdder(2); 
  print(add2(3) ); //5
}
```

Comment: `foo() => 1;` is the same as `foo() { return 1; }`

Comment: How about 'foo() {()=>1;)'? Is it the same as 'foo() {return ()=>1;)'?

Comment: `foo() => 1` is a function that returns `1`, `foo() { return () => 1; }` is a function that returns a function that returns `1`. To get `1` you need to call the former like `print(foo());` and the later like `print(foo()());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Dart each function without an explicit `return someValue;` returns `null`;

> The null object does not have a method 'call'.

`makeAdder` (`add2`) without `return` returns `null` and `null(3)` leads to the exception.

Comment: Hi, @ GünterZöchbauer, @SethLadd
I edited the article.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to quote two important note here. It might help others:

1. Though Dart is Optionally typed ( meaning, specifying the return type of a function such as int or void is optional ), it always recommended to specify type wherever possible. In your code, as a sign of good programming practice, do mention the return type.
2. If your function does not return a value then specify void. If you omit the return type then it will by default return `null`.

   > All functions return a value. If no return value is specified, the statement return `null`; is implicitly appended to the function body.

Comment: Can you put the source? Thanks in advance

Comment: Source: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#return-values