# Why does this Flutter example not have a return keyword?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am reading over the documentation for Flutter.

On [this page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html), I have observed the following curious method. In the method, the declared return type is Future. The method though, does not have the return keyword present anywhere. Why is this?

```
Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
  setState(() {
    _counter++;
  });
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final String dirName = directory.path;
  await File('$dir/counter.txt').writeAsString('$_counter');
}
```

I have been able to ascertain that all flutter functions return a value, and the default return value is null. But if this method always returns null, then why declare a return type of `Future<void>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the function is marked with the `async` modifier:

```dart
Future foo() async {
  print('hello world');
}
```

is equivalent to

```dart
Future foo() {
  try {
    print('hello world');
    return Future.value(null);
  } catch (err) {
    return Future.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Dart even-though it's an optionally typed language which means you can omit the type , It's recommended to provide it

When method does not have a return type , `return null` is appended , So in your example it's fit to `return Future.value(null);`

please see [Default return type in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737221/what-is-the-default-return-value-of-a-dart-function)